# Postfix Not Sending Or Receiving Emails

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot, roundcube

I followed this tutorial to setup a mailserver on my centos VPS: https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql-on-centos-6

And I am able to send emails to my account (sam@depressionforteens.com) but the emails aren't showing.

I've tried sending from roundcube so it is sent internally, my yahoo account and my gmail account.

When i send from my Yahoo I get this email bounced back in spam:

```
----- Forwarded Message -----

This is the mail system at host server.depressionforteens.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                  The mail system

<sam@depressionforteens.com>: unknown user: "sam"
Hello world!
```

This is the users table in my database:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----------------------------+---------------+
| email                      | password      |
+----------------------------+---------------+
| sam@depressionforteens.com | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+----------------------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also setup a forwarder like this:

```
mysql> select * from forwardings;
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| source                  | destination                |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| @depressionforteens.com | sam@depressionforteens.com |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And lastly this is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file http://pastebin.com/n7Zgy13X

I realise I am asking a lot but this is the first time I am setting up a mailserver and everything is haywire because nothing is giving the same result.

Also when I am trying to send an email from sam@depressionforteens.com from roundcube to my ymail or any external email I get:

```
SMTP Error (554): Failed to add recipient "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com" (5.7.1 <xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com>: Relay access denied).
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this? I have asked my host to add a reverse DNS entry which has been done.

And also in cloudflare I have an MX DNS record for depressionforteens.com --> server.depressionforteens.com

And lastly I also added a DKIM record in my DNS using opendkim. And I think that should be working?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your [MX records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/mx/depressionforteens.com/) on "depressionforteens.com" point to zoho? Seems like you're not using your own mail server anymore.

Comment: @henry I couldn't figure it out so I use zoho now. If anyone has any ideas though let me know cuz i'd like to get it working as well.